# Hibernate validator required for war deployment to Mule

Tags: spring-mvc, mule-studio, hibernate-validator

I’ve created a simple maven project that demonstrates Spring MVC accepts a request and returns a JSON object.

Here’s the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bg-SpringREST3.1</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTexample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>4.3.0.Final</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.13.v20130916</version>         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>JSON and XML RESTful web service example</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/application.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here's the application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<mvc:annotation-driven />
<!-- Use the message-converters element to specify the orders of message converters -->
<!--    
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="false">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter" />
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
-->
<context:component-scan base-package="integration.apps" />
```

Here is my RESTController.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class RESTController {

@RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestHeader("Accept") String acceptHeader) {

    return new User(id, "John Doe");
}
```

}

And my User.java

```
public class User {

private Long id;
private String name;

public User() {
}

public User(Long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

As far as I’m aware, I’m not using any validation. When I package the project and run Jetty within Eclipse, I receive no errors and the response to
http://localhost:8080/users/5
is

```
{"id":5,"name":"John Doe"}
```

Now I deploy the application in Mule following these steps

> 1. Create the following folder structure under scr/main/app/webapps
> 2. Drop the war file to this location
> 3. The mule configuration is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jetty="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jetty/current/mule-jetty.xsd">

<jetty:connector name="jettyConnector">
    <jetty:webapps directory="${app.home}/webapps" port="8083" />
</jetty:connector>

</mule>
```

Running dependency tree outside of Mule Anypoint studio. Note - I need to "mavenize" the mule project achieve this

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ RESTexample ---
[INFO] bg-SpringREST3.1:RESTexample:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.5:compile
```

Running dependency tree inside Mule Anypoint studio

```
[INFO] com.mycompany:springresttest:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.github.stephenc.eaio-uuid:uuid:jar:3.4.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.stephenc.eaio-grabbag:grabbag:jar:1.8.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:provided
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.mvel:mule-mvel2:jar:2.1.9-MULE-003:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:jar:0.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.common:mule-common:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-http:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-ssl:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:tomcat-util:jar:5.5.23:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- tomcat:tomcat-apr:jar:5.5.23:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:jar:1.3.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:1.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jdbc:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-dbutils:commons-dbutils:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.experlog:xapool:jar:1.5.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-jms:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.0_spec:jar:1.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-client:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-cxf:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-aegis:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.2.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jibx:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jibx:jibx-run:jar:1.2.4.5:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3:jar:1.1.3.4.O:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jibx:jibx-schema:jar:1.2.4.5:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.jibx:jibx-extras:jar:1.2.4.5:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-local:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-security:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.6.9:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.3:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.5.1-1:provided
[INFO] |  |        \- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.4.2-1:provided
[INFO] |  |           \- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.3.2-1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-rm:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-management:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-wstx-msv-validation:jar:2.5.9:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:jar:2011.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd:xsdlib:jar:2010.1:provided
[INFO] |  |     +- isorelax:isorelax:jar:20030108:provided
[INFO] |  |     \- relaxngDatatype:relaxngDatatype:jar:20020414:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-security:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-extras:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:1.3.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.11:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-tcp:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:9.1.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:provided
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-management:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-impl:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-tools:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- mx4j:mx4j-remote:jar:2.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.yourkit:yjp-controller-api-redist:jar:9.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  \- tanukisoft:wrapper:jar:3.2.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-scripting:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-builders:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.livetribe:livetribe-jsr223:jar:2.0.5:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.8.6:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-sxc:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.envoisolutions.sxc:sxc-xpath:jar:0.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.envoisolutions.sxc:sxc-runtime:jar:0.7.3:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.envoisolutions.sxc:sxc-core:jar:0.7.3:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.5.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.3.4.O:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.4:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:dom:9.1.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:jar:xqj:9.1.0.8:provided
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.mule.tests:mule-tests-functional:jar:3.5.0:test
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.0-M6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:jar:0.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:jar:1.46:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mule:mule-core:test-jar:tests:3.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0:test
[INFO] +- mockobjects:mockobjects-core:jar:0.09:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.9:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
```

Finally, the .classpath file for the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/J2SE-1.5">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Now, when I run the mule application (Mule server 3.5.0 CE) I get the following error

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider

Which is fine, if I uncomment the pom.xml entry on my rest project, I can run successfully in Mule.

So, my question, what is the difference between running the app in Eclipse with Jetty plugin and running in Mule again on Jetty.

Comment: How does your bean configuration look like. Can  you post the xml for that? Are you configuring LocalValidatorFactoryBean? You could run mvn dependency:tree to see what pulls in Validator. Last but not least, Eclipse maybe has the Validator jar on the classpath whereas Mule not.

Comment: Hi Hardy, I've updated the question with answers to your questions. It looks like the dependency tree for the project in eclipse doesn't have a validator on the class path. However, I don't know if I can be certain. I added the .classpath file from the project.

Comment: Also, sorry for the long delay in replying to you!